# Php save more Array into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

I'm trying to save arrays on a `MySQL` database with `PHP`.

The code inserts only the first line, if I have an `array` of 5 elements it just inserts the first element and the others and 4 don't save them for me.

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Thanks a lot.

```
<?php

//getting user values

$day = $_POST['Day'];
$nDay = $_POST['n_Day'];
$fieldOne = $_POST['Field_one'];
$fieldTwo = $_POST['Field_two'];
$timeOne = $_POST['Time_one'];
$timeTwo = $_POST['Time_two'];
$idR = $_POST['id_ristorante'];

$day_array = explode(",",$day);
$nDay_array = explode(",",$nDay);
$timeOne_array = explode(",",$timeOne);
$timeTwo_array = explode(",",$timeTwo);

$len = count($day_array and $nDay_array and $timeOne_array and $timeTwo_array);

$output=array();

//require database
require_once('db.php');

//checking if email exists
$conn=$dbh->prepare('SELECT id_ristorante FROM Orari WHERE id_ristorante=:idR');
$conn->bindParam(':idR', $idR, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$conn->execute();

//results
if($conn->rowCount() !==0){
    $output['isSuccess'] = 0;
    $output['message'] = "Orario già inserito";
} else {

     for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){

         $day = $day_array[$i];
         $nDay = $nDay_array[$i];
         $timeOne = $timeOne_array[$i];
         $timeTwo = $timeTwo_array[$i];

        $conn=$dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Orari (Day, n_Day, Field_one, Field_two, Time_one, Time_two, id_ristorante) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        //encrypting the password

        $conn->bindParam(1,$day);
        $conn->bindParam(2,$nDay);
        $conn->bindParam(3,$fieldOne);
        $conn->bindParam(4,$fieldTwo);
        $conn->bindParam(5,$timeOne);
        $conn->bindParam(6,$timeTwo);
        $conn->bindParam(7,$idR);


        $conn->execute();
        if($conn->rowCount() == 0) {
            $output['isSuccess'] = 0;
            $output['message'] = "Errore, riprova.";
        } elseif($conn->rowCount() !==0){
            $output['isSuccess'] = 1;
            $output['message'] = "Orari salvati!";

        }
    } 
}
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Comment: What is `count($day_array and $nDay_array and...` the `and` making it boolean evaluation - what did you mean `$len` should be?

Comment: it is used to count the number of elements in the array

Comment: There are multiple array in that statement, which count did you meant? I think if you just use count on the first one it will do

Comment: So, I have to save 5 items, when I put them all and 5 I save only the first item. Why don't you save them all? How do I count on all arrays?

Comment: If all has the same length then count just one. Better practice will be to count each and assign `$len` with the minimum

Comment: They all have the same length, I only inserted an array in the count, but it doesn't work, I always insert only one element

Comment: @dWinder It works if I count only one array, sorry but I was wrong to write the for loop. If you answer me I can assign the answer as a solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trying to do `count` on multiple array as:

```
$len = count($day_array and $nDay_array and $timeOne_array and $timeTwo_array);
```

The `and` cause the array to be boolean evaluated so the final assign to `$len` is 1 and that why the loop is done only once and only the first element is inserted to DB.

If all the array in the same length you should just do count on 1 of them as:

```
$len = count($day_array)
```

Better practice will be to do count on each on them and then assign `$len` with the minimum value

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$len = count($day_array and $nDay_array and $timeOne_array and $timeTwo_array);
```

To

```
$len = count($day_array) + count($nDay_array) + count($timeOne_array) + count($timeTwo_array);
```